# ECMA Support in Rhino Engine

Tags: javascript, rhino, javascript-engine

I know that Google's V8 engine supports upto the latest ECMAScript.But what is the latest ECMAScript that is supported by Rhino Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES6 has [partial support](http://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html),
according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Overview) ES 3 is fully supported. Not sure how the ES 5 support is.